# Possible to Reverse() an array, and sort another related to that sort? C#

Tags: arrays, sorting

You are able to sort an array related to another array using the [overloaded](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85y6y2d3(v=vs.110).aspx) version of Array.Sort()

But is this possible in any way for the Array.Reverse() method too? I am required to reverse sort an array, and sort a related array with the same sort as the reversed one.